# C# Android REST

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use Visual studio with Xamarin, c#.

I've done a REST service with Slim, PHP and MySql. It works fine (chrome ARC is awesome).

I want to be able to use POST, GET, PUT and DELETE from an application. Searching the web I found tons of things, but I didn't find anything for C# (always java, I'm sure I have to learn it very well!), or if it's for C# it is not suitable for mobile app (like using `System.Net.Http`).

(my rest uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as `Content-Type` of the Header, I don't know if it change something).

I have no clue, any suggestion is apreciated.

(Sorry if it could looks like a repost, but really, I didn't find any way searching for 3 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to find something that will allow you to use your REST service in an App?

Check this [blog post](http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/) on network services for Xamarin. It talks about using Refit which is a really nice library here is its [github](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit).

> What's Refit?
> Refit (along with http://json2csharp.com) allow you to really quickly create client libraries for Web APIs, by defining their contract in an Interface, and letting Refit do the grunt work of implementing the API for you. Here's an example:

```
public interface IGitHubService  
{
  [Get("/users/{user}/repos")]
  Task<List<Repo>> ListRepos(string user);
}
```

It also supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as you can see [here](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit#form-posts)

> Form posts
>
> For APIs that take form posts (i.e. serialized as application/x-www-form-urlencoded), initialize the Body attribute with BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded.
>
> The parameter can be an IDictionary:

```
public interface IMeasurementProtocolApi
{
    [Post("/collect")]
    Task Collect([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Dictionary<string, object> data);
}

var data = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"v", 1}, 
    {"tid", "UA-1234-5"}, 
    {"cid", new Guid("d1e9ea6b-2e8b-4699-93e0-0bcbd26c206c")}, 
    {"t", "event"},
};

// Serialized as: v=1&tid=UA-1234-5&cid=d1e9ea6b-2e8b-4699-93e0-0bcbd26c206c&t=event
await api.Collect(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Only one question. In that blog, in the restful part, the first row is a line (of code?) **Install-Package Refit**, I really don't know what should I do, is there something like a shell in visual studio/xamarin? By the way, I will study all this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: thats just adding a nuget package through command line(terminal) just add the nuget package as you would normally do

Comment: video on visual studio on how to add a nuget package https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8sx49NdCNk or on Xamarin Studio just double click the `Packages` folder and search for refit

Comment: This is the actual Docs on the **Install-Package** command if your interested https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#install-package using the package manager console for VS